Intel RST and Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
At my workplace we have a number of older devices from c.2016. The current plan was to retire them as they lack TPM 2.0 and cannot support Windows 11. This is quite unfortunate, as they are Toshiba Portege and HP Firefly laptops, which remain more than capable today especially with an inexpensive RAM upgrade and battery replacement, as well as running a less bloated operating system.
However, there is no option to change the mode of the SATA Controller in the BIOS of these laptops, meaning Intel RST cannot be disabled there, so I cannot install Ubuntu. I've reached out to both HP and Dynabook (Toshiba), and both confirmed that this cannot be done in the BIOS. Is there a way to bypass having to disable Intel RST for the installation of Ubuntu, or a way of enabling AHCI not involving the BIOS? Or are these laptops expensive tech waste?
Data preservation and dual-boot are not necessary.

Random suggestion, but try and set a BIOS password and reboot into the BIOS again. Then see if you can change the controller's mode. Some UEFI platforms (I'm thinking HPs but that's exactly what I'm unsure about) will allow to do more stuff if a BIOS password is set. Not sure if this would allow changing the controller's mode. I'm pretty sure that would allow disabling secure boot on some platforms though.

Find this Intel software. removal (setuprst.exe and setupoptanememory.exe - both from Dell But my Dell with only NVMe booted Ubuntu with RST on. It used Intel VMD driver, but not sure you can use with SATA.

You could give this a go -
Enter a terminal session and log in as root.
and then you could try modifying: /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
add the modules (each per new line):
ahci libahci

modify then this file: /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
and change < most > into < list>
run: update-initramfs -u
Reboot to BIOS, switch to AHCI and boot Ubuntu.
If needed, undo the changes of the files, (in case of any problems after boot) and:
re-run:
update-initramfs -u

Unless I misunderstand, you're saying I have to go to BIOS and switch to AHCI after installing modules on Ubuntu. To clarify, the entire problem is that I am unable to install Ubuntu as it requires I disable Intel RST (switching to AHCI in the BIOS), but the laptops' BIOS' doesn't have the setting to do so.

"I am unable to install Ubuntu as it requires I disable Intel RST" - Ah yes, I stand corrected, apologies.                                                                                                                                                                                                       Other than doing the RAM upgrade and installing Win 10, which I'm presuming you already thought of, you could check out this thread on OverClock - https://www.overclock.net/threads/how-to-turn-on-ahci-if-bios-does-not-have-the-option.1328344/. I'm not sure if it will help, but worth a try.

Seems you similarly hit a brick wall. As Win10 support is ending next year it isn't possible to use it in an enterprise environment because of our auditor's cybersecurity requirements around regular updates. I had hoped I was missing something simple as most of the posts here regarding Intel RST and Ubuntu were from 2020 or earlier, but it seems not.
